# About alignment of mathematics formulas

Tags: align

How can I implement the alignment like in the following image?

[image: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1kX_CbBVoMtSDQ0bVFaZ1JURS1lbXFPandBS01CZw]

Because the usual `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` command can not work, so I hope you can help me!

Thanks! Wait for your elegant codes or solutions...

Comment: Hi user9701, welcome to TeX.sx! Maybe you could change the question title into something a little more meaningful, so others facing the same issue can come across this thread more easily.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, you can use `align*`:

```
\begin{align*}
   &A(x) \\
={}&B(x) \\
={}&C(x)
\end{align*}
```

The `{}` after `=` is necessary to ensure correct spacing (which is better than what's obtained with `eqnarray`).

In normal cases one puts the relation symbol after the `&`, but in this case this would require the cumbersome `\mathrel{\phantom{=}} A(x)` as in Marco Daniel's answer (which is correct, nonetheless).

One should simply remind that `align` produces blocks of `rl` columns, *without* any space between them (and generous space between blocks). However, it takes special precautions so that a relation symbol *after* `&` has the correct spaces, but doesn't before the `&`. Here the easier solution is to put an empty subformula after the `=`, which produces the correct space.

Generally the relation symbol goes *after* the `&`, which is a rule to be broken only in a few special cases.

Answer (score 8):

One of the golden rules of amsmath is to use the separator before any relation. To suppress the first relation without using the space you can use the commands `\mathrel` in combination with `\phantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}} A(x) \\
&=B(x) \\
&=C(x)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the spacing it looks like a regular old `eqnarray` ([which should never be used anyway](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)).